# Elementary induction

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Using mathematical induction, show that if $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and
>   $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $a^{m+n}=a^ma^n$.

My induction skills is weak. Will I go about doing this with the same method, first show that it will equal $n=1$, then make the assumption that it will satisify $n+1$ and then show that it does in fact satisify $n+1$. Also, it seems very obvious but how will I prove this without induction?

Comment: Do you mean "then make the assumption that it will satisfy $n$"?

Comment: @GitGud Ops, yes that is what I intended to say. wink wink. I need to dedicate some hours studying induction.

Comment: You wish to prove that $(\forall a\in \mathbb{R})(\forall m\in \mathbb{N})(\forall n\in \mathbb{N})\bigl(a^{m+n}=a^ma^n\bigr)$.

Let $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and $m\in \mathbb{N}$ be given arbitrarily.

You now want to show that $(\forall n\in \mathbb{N})\bigl(a^{m+n}=a^ma^n\bigr)$. Prove this assertion using induction. From here you can just follow André's answer.

Comment: @GitGud thanks a lot !

Comment: About proving this without induction for $a>0$, you can prove the equivalent $(\forall a\in \mathbb{R}^+)(\forall m\in \mathbb{N})(\forall n\in \mathbb{N})\bigl(e^{\log {(a^{m+n}})}=e^{\log {(a^ma^n})}\bigr)$. However this probably doesn't work because it is very likely that you need induction to eventually define the exponential (I'd need to check). Plus for $a<0$ this approach wouldn't work.

Comment: @GitGud This will be a very neat to prove it, then I will have to use branches, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the induction on $n$. First verify that the result is true for $n=1$. You need to show that $a^{m+1}=a^m a$.  This is true, because it is part of the standard recursive definition of the function $a^q$.

Next we need to show that if the result is true when $n$ is equal to the specific integer $k$, then the result is true when $n=k+1$, the next integer.

So we need to prove that $a^{m+(k+1)}=a^ma^{k+1}$.

Note that $a^{m+(k+1)}=a^{(m+k)+1}$. By definition, this is $a^{m+k}a$.

By the induction hypothesis, we have $a^{m+k}=a^ma^k$.

So our expression $a^{m+k+1}$ is equal to $(a^ma^k)a$, which is $a^m(a^ka)$  by associativity of multiplication.

Finally, $a^ka=a^{k+1}$ by definition, and we conclude that $a^{m+k+1}=a^ma^{k+1}$. This is what we needed to prove.

**Remark:** This is a far from ideal problem to learn about induction.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Andre! Will an alternative way of proving this be similar to showing that, by definition, this is $a^{m+n}=a^ma^n$ because though I know it is true my book doesn't go over any properties of exponents where I can apply those properties formally in a proof.

Comment: I very much doubt that anyone would **define** $a^{m+n}$ to be $a^ma^n$. But in high school, and perhaps beyond, someone might say that $a^{m+n}=a^ma^n$ "because" $a^{m+n}$ is $m+n$ $a$'s multiplied together. But **if** you were assigned the problem of proving the result by induction, something very formal along the lines of my answer is expected.